# Installing assembly in GACUTIL with Invoke-Command in PowerShell (no permissions)

Tags: powershell, gac

I try to run a PowerShell-script that invokes a command. In that command I want to write a assembly to the GAC.

This is the code:

```
invoke-command -computername COMPUTERNAME -scriptblock { 
$gacUtil = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe"; 
& $gacutil '/nologo' '/if' '\\fileserver\..\Assembly.dll' 
}
```

PowerShell then returns this error:

```
Failure adding assembly to the cache: Administrator permissions are needed to use the selected options. Use an administrator command prompt to complete these tasks.
```

After some googling, I added a `-Credential` parameter to the invoke-command (with the Administrator-Credentials), but that still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are in vista, seven or above operative system, try execute powershell as administrator.

Comment: Already did that, thanks though

Comment: mmmh, a little googling give me only this approach to remote install assembly in GAC: http://www.cptloadtest.com/2005/07/26/Remote-Deployment-To-The-GAC.aspx

Comment: My assignment was to change the existing code that works with psexec, to a way that works with PowerShell :-) But this would be a great alternative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came from the assembly ('\fileserver..\Assembly.dll') to put in the GAC, not the gacutil.exe.

A good alternative posted by [Christian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520612/christian):
mmmh, a little googling give me only this approach to remote [install assembly in GAC](http://www.cptloadtest.com/2005/07/26/Remote-Deployment-To-The-GAC.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When we are getting this issue need to run the command prompt in Administrator mode.Hopefully this answer will help you .